# x86 Assembly: movsd instruction issue

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32, fasm

This is my problem:
I trying to use `scanf` (in `msvcrt.dll`) to input a single floating point value in `flat assembler` then I write a simple "scanf program" like this (in `C`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float a;

    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Just input: %f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

then using `cl.exe` to compile with `/FA` parameter to generate assembly file like this:

```
    lea eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET $SG2935
    call    _scanf
    add esp, 8
; Line 8
    cvtss2sd xmm0, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    sub esp, 8
    movsd   QWORD PTR [esp], xmm0
    push    OFFSET $SG2936
    call    _printf
    add esp, 12                 ; 0000000cH
```

What I missunderstand is `movsd` instruction. According here: http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/movsb.htm it `Move doubleword at address DS:(E)SI to address  ES:(E)DI` but I don't see any setting `esi`, `edi` up here and the `movsd` in generated source file have two parameters but in document in the link is it should not. Can someone explain me here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that web page is presenting less than the full picture.

It talks about the `A5` opcode but there are other variants such as `F2 0F` which allow movement between XMM registers and more arbitrary memory locations.

See [here](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc202.htm) for more detail.

Answer (score 17):

There are two x86 instructions with the same name!

1. MOVS/MOVSB/MOVSW/**MOVSD**/MOVSQ—Move Data from String to String
2. **MOVSD**—Move Scalar Double-Precision Floating-Point Value

Check intel [datasheet](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

This is the *other* MOVSD instruction, which is part of the SSE instructions. Here it is moving the double precision float value from xmm0, into memory.